# No warning in the Oracle generics example with erasure

Tags: java

Could you explain please why I don't get the warning in "Node n = mn" in the following 
Oracle generics example?

Also, could you explain MyNode is also generic as Node due to inheritance?
The reference to the original Oracle trail: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html.
I just found this bug about casting Node n = (MyNode)mn  https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8163188?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel

```
class Node<T> {

    public T data;

    public Node(T data) { this.data = data; }

    public void setData(T data) {
        System.out.println("Node.setData");
        this.data = data;
    }
}

public class MyNode extends Node<Integer> {
    public MyNode(Integer data) { super(data); }

    public void setData(Integer data) {
        System.out.println("MyNode.setData");
        super.setData(data);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyNode mn = new MyNode(5);
        Node n = mn;   // A raw type - compiler throws an unchecked warning
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the definition: "A generic type is a generic class or interface that is **parameterized over types**" MyNode is definitely not a generic type. For the rest of your question, can you be more specific? BTW, I do get that warning: "Node is a raw type. References to generic type Node<T> should be parameterized"

Comment: Thanks for the answer @aka-one . Now I understand that MyNode is not a generic type. So I clarify my question. And my question is just why I don't get the warning in this expression Node n = mn.